# Buscar datos en PowerPivot

Tags: base-de-datos

He importado a una tabla de excel con la opción Power Pivot, una base de datos de 1.200.000 filas con formato .txt (o .csv es lo mismo). Use Power Povot porque Excel no me permite ese número de filas.
El problema es que cuando intento buscar un dato con la opción Buscar (icono binoculares) me indica que no puede encontrar el dato. Eso ocurre aunque el dato esté en la tabla.
Cómo puedo buscar un datyo en PowerPivot?

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.